# Oracle SQL query with CASE and JOIN SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case

I'm trying to write an SQL query in Oracle to return employee salaries by grade. I'm using a subquery to determine a salary range for each grade.
The query below doesn't work, it system returns the "*ORA-00936: missing expression*" error.

What am I doing wrong?

```sql
SELECT a.last_name, a.salary, b.grade_level, b.lowest_sal, b.highest_sal 
FROM employees a 
JOIN (
    SELECT 
       CASE salary 
        WHEN BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THAN 'A' 
       WHEN BETWEEN 3000 AND 5999 THAN 'B' 
        ELSE 'C' 
        END AS grade_level,
       MIN(salary) AS lowest_sal, MAX(salary) AS highest_sal
   FROM employees 
   GROUP BY grade_level)  b 
ON(a.salary BETWEEN b.lowest_sal AND b.highest_sal) 
ORDER BY last_name;
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desred results.  I will note that Oracle does not allow table aliases in `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: Case...when...then (not than)

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1):

I think window functions are a better approach:

```
SELECT e.*,
       MIN(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_level) as lowest_sal,
       MAX(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_level) as highest_sal
FROM (SELECT (CASE WHEN salary BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THAN 'A'
                   WHEN salary BETWEEN 3000 AND 5999 THAN 'B'
                   ELSE 'C'
              END) AS grade_level,
             e.*
      FROM employees e
     ) e
ORDER BY last_name ;
```

Note that this also fixes the `CASE` expression, which is also syntactically incorrect in your query.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon and HelenA <br>. SELECT a.last_name, a.salary, b.grade_level, b.lowest_sal, b.highest_sal
FROM employees a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN salary BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THEN 'A'
    WHEN  salary BETWEEN 3000 AND 5999 THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
    END AS grade_level,
    MIN(salary) AS lowest_sal, MAX(salary) AS highest_sal
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY salary) b
ON(a.salary BETWEEN b.lowest_sal AND b.highest_sal)
ORDER BY last_name ;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gordon and HelenA 
. Your comments helped me to find mistakes in my code.

1. wrong syntax in my CASE expression
2. table alias in the GROUP BY.

```sql
SELECT a.last_name, a.salary, b.grade_level, b.lowest_sal, b.highest_sal
FROM employees a
JOIN (
  SELECT CASE
     WHEN salary BETWEEN 1000 AND 2999 THEN 'A'
       WHEN  salary BETWEEN 3000 AND 5999 THEN 'B'
       ELSE 'C'
       END AS grade_level,
   MIN(salary) AS lowest_sal, MAX(salary) AS highest_sal
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY salary) b
ON(a.salary BETWEEN b.lowest_sal AND b.highest_sal)
ORDER BY last_name ;
```

Output:

```
LAST_NAME   SALARY  GRADE_LEVEL LOWEST_SAL  HIGHEST_SAL
Abel        11000   C           11000       11000
Davies       3100   B           3100        3100
De Haan     17000   C           17000       17000
Ernst        6000   C           6000        6000
Fay          6000   C           6000        6000
Gietz        8300   C           8300        8300
Grant        7000   C           7000        7000
Hartstein   13000   C           13000       13000
```